# Odoo10 getting res currency id

Tags: currency, odoo-10

I am using `print(currency_id)` the result is `res.currency(1,)` but how will I use this output in a loop. For example `if currency_id == res.currency(1,)` or something like that, or is there a easy way to get currency id like `res.currency==dollar`.

My aim is if currency is $, write to field dollar.
How can I get product currency type? Like is it $ or £ whatever.

Comment: Look at the table `res_currency` in the database. For € you can use `if currency_id.name == 'EUR':`